# Understanding how classname is read in react, if it is possible to pass both string and template literals into the same classname property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I am wondering how does javascript read `className` inside `return()`? How do we pass both a string and Template literals into it? I know that we can add class names as string using `className="class1 class2"` and `className={function}` to add a javascript function into it. Sorry if this is a silly question but how can we incorporate both methods into the same line? I realised I have been using react for sometime now without realising how exactly it converts `className` in react into html `class`.

An example would be this line which I am trying to write better `className={ sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu' }` - basically if `sidebar` is set to true then classes `nav-menu` and `active` are added to the component while if it is false then only `nav-menu` is shown. I tried using javscript interpolation but failed as I'm not sure how react reads this and how it executes anthing on the right of `className=`.

Specifically if it helps, what I tried was `className={`side-menu`, sidebar ? 'active' : '' }` but it didn't work. Is there a better way of writing this code and understanding? Thank you!

Comment: There's a library called clsx that helps with this. In your case, all you need to do is `className={\`side-menu${sideBar ? " active" : ""}\`}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string template literal:

```
<Component className={`${getClassName()} class-x ${sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}`} />
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted to know so I guess it can read classnames in javascript with space in between to separate different classnames thank you!